# ¿Declarar longitud de columnas numéricas en postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

¿Cómo puedo declarar el máximo de caracteres a ingresar en una columna de tipo `integer`?

Es decir, en MySQL puedo decir `int(4)` y lo toma normalmente. Pero en PostgreSQL me da error en este tipo de campo y en otros, pero en un campo de tipo `varchar` sí me deja poner la longitud.

¿Por qué en unos me deja y en otros no? Y en los que no me deja, ¿cómo sé cual es la longitud que permite ingresar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Cómo puedo declarar el máximo de caracteres a ingresar en una columna de tipo `integer`?

Para poder especificar la cantidad de dígitos que quieres permitir en una columna numérica, debes usar el tipo `NUMERIC`, no `INTEGER`:

Ejemplo:

```
create table tbl (
  a numeric(4)
)
```

> ¿Por qué en unos me deja y en otros no?

Porque cada tipo ha sido diseñado con un propósito diferente. Algunos tipos como `INTEGER` son menos flexibles en el aspecto que has notado, pero tienden a consumir menos espacio y con excelentes para cálculos aritméticos rápidos. Pero otros tipos como `NUMERIC` fueron diseñados con mayor flexibilidad, pero usualmente toman mas espacio. Es tu responsabilidad escoger el tipo mas adecuado a tus necesidades.

> Y en los que no me deja, ¿cómo sé cual es la longitud que permite ingresar?

Para eso está la documentación en [el sitio oficial de PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org).

En particular, en la página siguiente encontrarás toda la inforamción necesario respecto a los diferentes tipos: [Chapter 8. Data Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype.html).

Por ejemplo, a partir de allí puedes encontrar información sobre [el tipo `INTEGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT), donde allí puedes ver que ese tipo siempre consume 4 bytes y acepta valores entre `-2147483648` y `+2147483647`.

Pero también, mas abajo puedes encontrar inforamción sobre el uso del tipo `NUMERIC`.